# how to reset /dev/ttyS0

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, serial

I'm trying to connect to a Khepera robot using serial interface (running Scientific Linux 6.1) I used the command `screen /dev/ttyS0` to communicate which worked OK, but then I wanted to close it and use MATLAB, but I found no way to close that session, so I just clicked X on the terminal window running screen.

Now my ttyS0 port cannot be opened. Both MATLAB and screen says that it cannot open that port.

**How can I reset the ttyS0 port?** I mean one choice is to restart the computer. But how to do it without restarting?

**What is the proper way to terminate a serial communication?**

Also, what does the following command do? I've found it with Google and run it but nothing happened. Did it do anything bad what I need to fix?

```
/sbin/agetty -L -f /etc/issueserial 9600 ttyS0 vt100
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can issue the command `screen -ls` to get a status of all current screen
sessions. Then use the `screen` `-r` option to "reattach" to the disconnected
`screen` session and the `-X` option to kill the session.

Here's an example shell session.  I'm using the `-d -m` options to start the
`screen` session in "detached" mode (in the background) to simulate closing the
session using the `X on the terminal window running screen`.  The `5207` from
`screen`'s `-ls` output is the process ID number, which will be used to
"reattach" to that specific `screen` session.

```
$ screen -d -m /dev/ttyS0
$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
    5207..host  (10/04/2011 10:16:50 AM)    (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-user.

$ screen -r 5207 -X kill
$ screen -ls 
No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-user.

$
```

Comment: I did just that and could kill my process. However, my /dev/ttyS0 is still busy after this. /var/run/screen/S-<user> is empty. How do I free ttyS0?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the proper way to terminate a serial communication?

From a programming point of view – simply `close()` the opened file descriptor. Exiting the program does that automatically. However, you did *not* exit Screen.

One of the most commonly used GNU Screen features is the ability to *detach* and reattach to sessions. When you closed the window, the "server" part of Screen remained running, and you can reattach to it with `screen -r`.

Use <kbd>C-a</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd> to actually kill a Screen window.

> Also, what does the following command do? I've found it with Google and run it but nothing happened. Did it do anything bad what I need to fix?
>
> ```
> /sbin/agetty -L -f /etc/issueserial 9600 ttyS0 vt100
> ```

[`agetty` is a TTY monitor program.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getty_%28Unix%29) Its job is to reinitialize the terminal device's configuration and to display a login prompt; you can see it in action by switching to the console login prompts at `tty1`...`tty6`. <sup>1</sup>

In this case, when you started `agetty` on your end, it sent a login prompt<sup>2</sup> to the robot, which probably discarded it as garbage. It is normally harmless, unless the robot somehow interprets "`login:`" as "initiate world takeover". The configuration done by `agetty` shouldn't break anything either.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that getty does not handle actual logins – it just asks for the user name. Once you enter it, `agetty` starts `/sbin/login` to perform the login process.

<sup>2</sup> It would also have sent the contents of `/etc/issueserial` text file, but since you found the command on Google, it's most likely that you don't even have that file.

Comment: Thanks for the writeup. I still don't understand how can I reinitialize the ttyS0 port after I incidentally closed the Screen program. I tried with ps and there was no process called screen, but the port was still in use. What can I do now? (other than restart)

Comment: @zsero: *Reattach* like I suggested. (The Screen server calls itself "SCREEN", in upper case.) Alternatively, run `lsof /dev/ttyS0` as root and you'll see all programs using the port.